# Сравнение свойств объектов в цикле Js

Tags: javascript

Есть функция:

```
function checkShot(){
    for(var count = 1; shot.x != ship.x && shot.y != ship.y; count++ ){
        alert('не верно!');
        shot.setX();
        shot.setY();
    }
    alert('верно ' + count);
}
```

По идее пока оба равенства не будут достигнуты,цикл будет повторяться, но на деле получается достаточно выполнения одного любого равенства..... подскажите почему так происходит?

Вот полный код:

```
function myRandom (from, to)  {
return Math.floor((Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
}

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function shotX(){
    var data = prompt('Введите X координату?','0 - 10');
    if (data >= 0 && data <= 10 && isNumeric(data)){
    return data;
    }else{
    alert('Необходимо ввести число от 0 до 10');
    return shotX();
    }
}

function shotY(){
    var data = prompt('Введите Y координату?','0 - 10');
    if (data >= 0 && data <= 10 && isNumeric(data)){
    return data;
    }else{
    alert('Необходимо ввести число от 0 до 10');
    return shotY();
    }
}

function checkShot(){
    for(var count = 1; shot.x != ship.x && shot.y != ship.y; count++ ){
        alert('Мимо!');
        shot.setX();
        shot.setY();
    }
    alert('бла бла бла ' + count);

}
var ship = {
x: myRandom (0, 10),
    y: myRandom (0, 10)
};

console.log(ship.x);
console.log(ship.y);

//координаты выстрела
var shot = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    setX: function(){
        return this.x = shotX();
    },
    setY: function(){
            return this.y = shotY();
        }
};
shot.setX();
shot.setY();
checkShot();
```

Comment: у вас не понятно откуда берутся `shot` и `ship`. Вы их убрали для сокращения записи? или их в функции нет?

Comment: абсолютно верно, это два различных объекта со свойствами x и y, которые сравниваются между собой.

Comment: вопрос в том, где они в вашей функции? как попадают? или они глобальные?

Comment: Также убедитесь, что у свойств `.x` и `.y` совпадают не только значения, но и типы. Ведь `shot.x=1;` и `shot.x='1';` не одно и то же :)

Comment: добавил полный код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При истинности любого равенства: `shot.x == ship.x` или `shot.y == ship.y`, результатом выражения `(shot.x != ship.x && shot.y != ship.y)` будет `false` - что является сигналом для прерывания цикла.

Используйте:

`!(shot.x == ship.x && shot.y == ship.y)`

или

`(shot.x != ship.x || shot.y != ship.y)`

Comment: Хорошо,а как тогда избежать этого и добиться прерывание цикла,только при `shot.x == ship.x` **и** `shot.y == ship.y` ?

Comment: И все же почему так происходило? Там же стоит оператор `&&`, а не `||`, что подразумевает _если это так_ **и** _это так_ **то**..... ???

Comment: Напишите словами условие, при котором цикл должен продолжаться, и Вы, вероятно, сами увидите ошибку в логике Вашего булевского выражения.

Comment: цикл выполняется _пока_ true И true. Как только любое из неравенств не срабатывает false И true дает false и цикл останавливается.